# 2-second delay when changing Qpushbutton stylesheet image

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

When clicking button I change the image, as if it was selected...

[image]

To make this change I leave everyone with the default image and just change the button that was pressed, but these 3 lines cause the program to have a delay of 2 seconds

```
main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_clique_na_imagem.setStyleSheet(style + "clique na figura off.png);}")
main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_clique_na_letra.setStyleSheet(style + "clique na letra que falta off.png);}")  
main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_digt_nome_imagem.setStyleSheet(style + "digite o nome da figura off.png);}")
```

here's how the function is called

main.py

```
def atv_escolhida(self, nome_atividade):    
        self.atividades.atividade_escolhida_fun(self, nome_atividade)
```

atividades.py

```
def atividade_escolhida_fun(self, main_app, nome_atividade):
        # main_app = self da classe main.py
        # self.set_atividade_escolhida(nome_atividade)
        self.atividade_escolhida = nome_atividade

        style = """
        QPushButton:hover {
            border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        QPushButton{
            border-image: url(:/atvimg/app_imagens/"""

        # TODO verificar isso
        main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_clique_na_imagem.setStyleSheet(style + "clique na figura off.png);}")
        main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_clique_na_letra.setStyleSheet(style + "clique na letra que falta off.png);}")  
        main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_digt_nome_imagem.setStyleSheet(style + "digite o nome da figura off.png);}")
        
        if(nome_atividade == "tela_atividade_digt_nome_imagem"):
            main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_digt_nome_imagem.setStyleSheet(style + "digite o nome da figura on.png);}")
        elif(nome_atividade == "tela_atividade_clique_na_imagem"):
            main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_clique_na_imagem.setStyleSheet(style + "clique na figura on.png);}")
        elif(nome_atividade == "tela_atividade_clique_na_letra"):
            main_app.ui.btn_tela_atividade_clique_na_letra.setStyleSheet(style + "clique na letra que falta on.png);}")
```

Comment: your question is unclear, explain better please. And provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Instead reassigning stylesheet you can use fixed stylesheet with two (or more) appearances of specific widgets depending on value of dynamic property of `QObject`. Change dynamic property with `widget.setProperty(propName, propValue)` and call `style.unpolish(widget)` and `style.polish(widget)`. This could fix delay. I used `background-color` instead of images to demonstrate concept. Adopt it to `border-image` yourself please.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class View(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        buttons = []
        for i in range(3):
            name = "button{}".format(i+1)
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
            button.setObjectName(name)
            layout.addWidget(button)
            button.setProperty("selected", False)
            button.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
            button.clicked.connect(lambda on, i=i: self.setSelected(i))
            buttons.append(button)
        self._buttons = buttons
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
        QPushButton:hover { border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);}
        #button1[selected="false"] {background-color: #cccccc;}
        #button2[selected="false"] {background-color: #cccccc;}
        #button3[selected="false"] {background-color: #cccccc;}

        #button1[selected="true"] {background-color: #ccccff;}
        #button2[selected="true"] {background-color: #ccffcc;}
        #button3[selected="true"] {background-color: #ffcccc;}
        """)

    def setSelected(self, i):
        style = self.style()
        for j, button in enumerate(self._buttons):
            button.setProperty("selected", i == j)
            style.unpolish(button)
            style.polish(button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    view = View()
    view.show()
    app.exec()
```